# IAM User S3 permission and Bucket permission in S3 which one will execute first?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an IAM user and i have given S3 full access to specific user, also i am giving some access permissions in S3 bucket separately, i want to know which one will execute first.
either it will give full access to my user according to IAM or it will work according to the S3 permission

Comment: The way S3 authorisation works is it will first check your IAM principal and then will move to check bucket level policy. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It will use *both* of the permissions.

First, any `Deny` permissions will be evaluated (on the IAM User, any IAM Group they belong to, and in the Bucket Policy). If the request matches a Deny policy, then the request is denied.

Next, all `Allow` permissions are evaluated. If the request matches an Allow policy, then the request is allowed.

So, in the absence of any Deny policies, a request will be permitted as long as *any* permission grants the access.